# Syntax not understood

Tags: c++

What is the significant of * in this line please ?

```
CourseClass::CourseClass(Professor* professor){
}
```

Comment: It denotes that `professor` is a *pointer*, see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: It probably should have been `CourseClass::CourseClass(Professor& professor)` because the professor is not optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says the function argument is of pointer type.

```
void foo1(int bar) { }  // foo1 accepts an integer argument

void foo2(int *bar) { }  // foo2 accepts an integer pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

this function would accept pointer parameter of type Professor